# How have you been helped by programmers.SE?

Tags: discussion

I'm wondering for the sake of meta knowledge, how programmers.SE has helped you as a programmer?

Comment: and career advice

Comment: I don't think I understand what you think is lacking. There are lots of questions about how to be a programmer, in fact all the question are about that one way or another. What specific things do you feel this site is missing?

Comment: @Matt missing is anything practical, I can pick up code complete and learn much more while taking a dump than I can scrolling down the home page of programmers.SE.  I think the topics not covered in Code Complete for instance, are the most interesting topics here.  Maybe all those questions have been asked, "How much space to put between parens" is a good question, an expert answer or two would be awesome.  We may need to start requiring references the way other sites do.  Or at least strong logic.

Comment: This certainly took a left turn after the first sentence.

Comment: If you don't like it don't use it.

Comment: @mmyers, feel free to embrace the `<strike>`.  I think you're right maybe I should take out the rant.

Comment: "I think the only advice most people can give on this site is A.) Don't do that and B.) Use such and such a framework." Prove it.

Comment: I strongly disagree that code formatting questions are good questions. There is only one answer to any formatting question: The most important thing is to be consistent, if your company or side project (open source or otherwise) has a set of formatting rules, follow them. Other than that I don't see what can be said that isn't pointless opinion. I don't see how that can teach you about being a programmer.

Comment: It would be nice to see other types of questions that delve more deeply into the psyche of programming and programmers and has evidence to back it up. I agree that sometimes when I read answers it feels like people are regurgitating something they've read in Pragmatic Programmer, or something.

Comment: @Matt you seem to have adopted [this awful](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/1653/this-question-about-word-meanings-was-closed-as-off-topic-but-does-not-seem-to-b) mindset which you originally didn't have. That question shouldn't have been closed and I'm going to go vote to reopen it right now.  But yeah, a more fruitful discussion of topics in programming books would be a good start.

Comment: @badp, the problem is I do like it, if I hadn't had the first question I asked in months pointlessly closed yesterday I wouldn't even be here bothering everyone with my idle banter. But as I see it, things are not going so well, nor have they for a while.  Maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: No, you're not wrong.

Comment: If you'd like to continue our discussion, I'm in chat.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to answer the question of someone [dealing with a personal problem](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/43260/how-to-stay-creative-when-going-through-tough-emotional-times-divorce-family-de) by relating it to my own, and this helped me understand my problem better.

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, I learned about [lambda expressions](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/33663/delphi-doesnt-have-lambda-expressions-and-im-a-delphi-programmer-what-am-i-mis) and how to do them in Delphi. I thought that was a pretty cool thing and I seriously didn't know it before.  I'm glad I asked.

Answer (score 0):

As a "programmer" it hasn't been much help. As a "development team lead" I find it gets me thinking about questions my developers haven't voiced yet. It helps me stay ahead of the game and solve problems as soon as they crop up. It feels a bit like cheating to be honest.